# Create react native app and yarn not running after installing npm modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement `react-navigation` into an app made using `create-react-native-app`. The problem is after installing the npm module (or any other) nothing works. I get build error like `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactPropTypes.string')`.
Googled and followed issues on github and still haven't found a solution. Could some one help me out please?

package.json

```
{
    "name": "TestApp",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest-expo": "~1.0.1",
        "react-native-scripts": "0.0.31",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
    },
    "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native-scripts start",
        "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
        "android": "react-native-scripts android",
        "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^17.0.0",
        "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-native": "^0.45.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
    }
}
```

yarn v0.24.5
npm v3.10.10
Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a version mis-match between react and react-native. Installing react-native@"0.45.1" with react@"16.0.0-alpha.12" fixed this for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! Silly me. It solved the issue then I got another build error which then I resolved by changing the header search path in xcode.